# how to configure maven to generate more detail Jmeter results similar to the view Results Tree in Jmeter GUI?

Tags: maven, jmeter, bamboo

I'm trying to integrate Jmeter tests with maven and running from bamboo. I see the Test result as passed( see my output from bamboo or same result even if I run locally)but it doesn't provide me more details like my request , reply xml similar to what I see when I run the scripts from Jmeter GUI under View Results Tree. I even tried with the analysis plugin but still didn't see what I expected.
Is there a way in maven(like any plugin) that generates detail report similar to what we see in the View Results Tree?
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
[info] Completed Test: Demo Test.jmx
16-Sep-2015 13:49:32    [INFO]  
16-Sep-2015 13:49:32    [INFO] Test Results:
16-Sep-2015 13:49:32    [INFO]  
16-Sep-2015 13:49:32    [INFO] Tests Run: 1, Failures: 0
```

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>jmeter-demo</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>jmeter-demo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
          <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
          <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-Maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>verify</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>analyze</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>
                <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/testresults/</targetDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform some additional configuration to store request and response data. Modify your `<execution>` section as follows:

```
<execution>
    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
    <phase>verify</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>jmeter</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <propertiesJMeter>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.url>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.url>
            <jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders>
        </propertiesJMeter>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

and you'll get result file suitable for analysis with the View Results Tree listener.

References:

- JMeter properties setting via Maven - [Modifying Properties](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties)
- JMeter properties in general - [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Be aware that storing any extra information increases Disk IO on JMeter side and in case of large responses or large number of threads or both can ruin your test so use these settings carefully and revert them to defaults once you're happy with your script for the actual load test.

Comment: I'm still not seeing details in my bamboo output even after adding the above piece. Am I missing something here? It is same as before.

Comment: The answer is about JMeter, request and response details should be in .jtl files under `target/jmeter/tesults/` folder. If you need to change Bamboo output to include extra details - ask questions at Bamboo forum

Comment: Thank you. I can see the details now. But I'd like to see the details in the bamboo output since I need to login to the agent everytime for test results. I will ask in bamboo forum.

Comment: when I run the tests having two .jmx files in /src/test/Jmeter only the first one is being run by the jmeter-analysis-Maven-plugin. So I've added two lines like this to process two jtl 
but still runs the first one only, how do I specify to process all .jtl files in analysis plugin?           <source>${project.basedir}/target/jmeter/**/*.jtl</source>  
        <source>${project.basedir}/target/jmeter/**/*.jtl</source>

Comment: can anyone please respond how to process multiple .jtl files using the Jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin? I tried all possible ways but no luck.